# Trouble instantiating a variable in a Yahtzee scorecard type program

Tags: java, variables, constants

Okay so I am writing a program for the game Yahtzee, and I am trying to figure out how to store the value of each round in that rounds scorecard box, and continuing to fill out the other sections of the scorecard. The way I am doing this is by this section of my code:

```
  public static void finalScoreCard(int choice, int points)
  {
 int ones = one(choice, points);
 int twos = two(choice, points);
 int threes = three(choice, points);
 int fours = four(choice, points);
 int fives = five(choice, points);
 int sixes = six(choice, points);
 int threeKind = nine(choice, points);
 int fourKind = ten(choice, points);
 int fullHouse = eleven(choice, points);
 int smallStr = twelve(choice, points);
 int largeStr = thirteen(choice, points);
 int yahtzee = fourteen(choice, points);
 int chance = fifteen(choice, points);
}

 public static int one(int choice, int points)
 {
final int score;
if (choice == 1)
    score = points;

if (choice != 1 && score != points)
    return 0;
else
    return score;
 }
```

so the "one" method is supposed to take in the choice number and points parameters, and then return the score if that box is chosen. 
I want my program to instantiate "score" if the user picks that choice option, and assign "score" with "points". And then after they have done this, the method should just return the score after every round, or return 0 until "score" has been instantiated. The thing is, I do not understand how to save the value of "score" multiple times around. This whole program is in a for loop that runs 13 times. 
Thanks

Comment: You want us to write your code for you?

Comment: Should this be labelled homework?

Comment: You could always declare `score` to be a static class variable. `private static int score;` I'm not sure if that's what you're asking... it's a pretty confusing question to be honest.

Comment: @CookieOfFortune The homework tag is deprecated. (Homework questions are still allowed, but they must still follow all the guidelines for good questions)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using one method and a switch.

```
public void doSomething(int choice, int points)
{
  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
      ...
      break;
    case 2:
     ...
     break;
    default:
     //handle default case
  }
}
```

Oh and make `score` a private variable. Assuming the methods and variable are in the same class it should be fine.

```
private int score ;
```